# How to list all NetBeans warnings with FindBugs plugin?

Tags: java, netbeans, findbugs

I'll try to use FindBug plugin to list all of code errors, but the plugin misses the warnings (e.g. "Add @Override annotation", "Equals on incompatible classes", "Unused import", etc.).

What settings did I miss?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the **`Source -> Inspect`** Window you have to select **`Configuration: All Analyzers`**. Furthermore its possible to customize your Analyzers-settings by clicking **`Manage`**